# Firebase AdMob warning: 'the ad request was successful but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory'

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, admob, banner-ads

I'm trying to integrate **firebase admob** in my app with react native, everything works with [testID](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads) of a Banner ('ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716'), and the Banner is displayed correctly.

But when I'm using my **bannerID** it shows me this warning ('*the ad request was successful but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory*') and no ad is displayed.

So it's not somenthing about my code, but about my **AdMob account** and I can't solve it.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FttdQZpIJscaQ6OPgAD02u-mWxL-pBDZ) you can find info about my AdMod account and about my React Native code.

Answer (score 1):

If your AdMob account is new then for few hours and Please don't forget to fill up Payment info on AdMob dashboard.

Comment: I create my AdMob account several months ago, and I filled up with my payments info as you can see on my drive, what else should I do ?

Comment: If you don't face any issues with test ads and facing issues only with live ads then it's definitely related to your AdMob directly. Just wait for 12-24 hrs, if nothing happens then contact support.

Comment: Any other tips?

Comment: My bannerID should works if the app is not on Play Store, rigth ?

Comment: Yes, it'll work even if the app is not live on the store.

Answer (score 1):

If your have this error,

> no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory

then your code is correct. Admob just doesn't have any ads to display for your app (your country, your type of ads are determinants). So just wait for one or two day max . It  will appear automatically.

You can run your app with test Ad currently. No need to worry

If you want to contact Admob support here's the [link](https://support.google.com/admob?source=404#topic=7383088)

Comment: And if after 2 days having the same warning??

Comment: if it is saying that `the ad request was successful` . then there will no any warning . still you can contact ad support team anytime

Comment: Can you post the link to contact them?

Comment: Thanks, but how can i write to them to have an answer?

Comment: @DanieleMenchetti you can submit you issue there is you haven't find any relevant to you. they will get back to you . or else you can post new answer also here

Comment: After writing my issue I only received lots of similiar result, but I can't see where can I wrote my own issue

Comment: @DanieleMenchetti if this answer helps you .  you can accept it

Comment: No friends I don't know how to write to Google Support,

Comment: @DanieleMenchetti brother i can't teach you how to write message